# Mongoose and Next.js passing ID's between schema and patching collections. What is best practice?(dangerous question, I know)

Tags: mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

I'm still a beginner so take it easy, I haven't found any instructions on how to this so it might be that I am making it overcomplicated, or it is more simple than I imagine.

I have two schemas that are interacting.

### Cars

```
`import mongoose from "mongoose";
import "./DamageReport";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const carSchema = new Schema({
  licensePlateNumber: { type: String, required: true },
  currentDamageReports: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "DamageReport" }],
  resolvedDamageReports: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "DamageReport" }],
});

const Car = mongoose.models.Car || mongoose.model("Car", carSchema);

export default Car;`
```

### Damage Report

```
`import mongoose from "mongoose";
import "./Car";

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const damageReportSchema = new Schema({
  car: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Car", required: true },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["body", "mechanical", "electrical"],
    required: true,
  },
  description: { type: String },
  photo: { type: String },
  resolved: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  isDrivable: { type: Boolean },
});

const DamageReport =
  mongoose.models.DamageReport ||
  mongoose.model("DamageReport", damageReportSchema);

your text`export default DamageReport;`
```

So, when a car is created, there are obviously no damage reports associated with it. What I want to do , when I post a new damage report, is get the _id of the car entry from the license plate number (enum selector in front end)...
My first question here is, do I do this in the schema (damageReport.js), in the api route file, or in the front end. Is there a best practice? Is this middleware?

Then, I want to push the _id of the newly created damage report entry into the currentDamageReports key in the relevant entry in the car collection. As above, where is the best place to perform this?

Much appreciated.

Many hours of youtubers and web dev simplified.